Is there any information[like, assertion or some other data], we can extract from pac4j SP in case of jee based application for internal validation?
We are been able to connect to our IDP using the reference of the demo app based on JEE https://github.com/pac4j/jee-pac4j-demo by providing necessary data for Hana IDP.
Our product internal architecture is based on

JEE[Frontend], core Java[backend]  & C++ [backend].
JEE request for an enterprise session by requesting a user credential OR by trusted Authentication to backend. On successful validation backend provides an enterprise session for the user.

Pac4j JEE based implementation and SAML is suitable for our architecture.
But, One problem we are facing:

After user authentication happened between IDP and SP. How the user can be authenticated in our backend for a valid session[of our enterprise session]?
Is there any information[like, assertion or some other data], we can extract from pac4j SP and pass in our backend for further verification in backend side?

Here the reference code we have used for connecting and authenticated with Hana IDP.
public Config build(final Object... parameters) {

......

final SAML2Configuration cfg = new SAML2Configuration("resource:samlKeystore.jks",
                                            "Password1",
                                            "Password1",
                                            "resource:samltest-providers.xml");
                                            
......

cfg.setMaximumAuthenticationLifetime(3600);
cfg.setServiceProviderEntityId("http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/callback?client_name=SAML2Client");
        
cfg.setServiceProviderMetadataPath(new File("sp-metadata.xml").getAbsolutePath());
final SAML2Client saml2Client = new SAML2Client(cfg);

......

final Clients clients = new Clients("http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/callback", oidcClient, saml2Client, facebookClient,
        twitterClient, formClient, indirectBasicAuthClient, casClient, stravaClient, parameterClient,
        directBasicAuthClient, new AnonymousClient(), casProxy);
        
final Config config = new Config(clients);
config.addAuthorizer("admin", new RequireAnyRoleAuthorizer("ROLE_ADMIN"));
config.addAuthorizer("custom", new CustomAuthorizer());

.....

final DefaultSessionLogoutHandler defaultCasLogoutHandler = new DefaultSessionLogoutHandler();
defaultCasLogoutHandler.setDestroySession(true);
config.setSessionLogoutHandler(defaultCasLogoutHandler);

return config;
}

Your valuable advice will be really helpful.
Regards
Rajib

When you have web services and web applications, it would be better to use a protocol like OAuth/OIDC for communication.
With SAML, the way to communicate with your backend is up to you: I recommend using a JWT, signed at least (and maybe encrypted if data needs to be protected) to be able to transport the user profile.

Thanks for your reply.
Our product is quite old. To support few customers need, we need to support SAML.
Our security threat point is in JEE application side between authentication towards IDP[using pac4j] and enterprise session creation for the same user in our backend. There should not be of any hack of different user in between.
On Your proposal of JWT:

Do SAML SP for pac4j return JWT formatted data in any place for the logged on user?
If there is, can you please help us with some reference code/sample to extract/handle in terms of JWT for pac4j SAML?


After a SAML authentication, you will get a pac4j user profile. Use the JwtGenerator to build your JWT and the HeaderClient + JwtAuthenticator to validate it. See: https://www.pac4j.org/5.7.x/docs/authenticators/jwt.html and https://www.pac4j.org/5.7.x/docs/clients/http.html

Thanks for your suggestion.
We had internal discussion about your proposal.
As per our architecture, WebApp and backend are two different individual component. It’s a legacy architecture.
As per your proposal, user SAML authentication is done in webApp level and then WebApp to send the JWT to backend.
But, backend is lack with the trustworthiness of WebApp, as it is a different component to trust on the JWT.
BTW, anyway can we extract Assertion received from IDP and do the user authentication validation directly in the backend[not in the WebApp level]?

You can perform the SAML authentication at the backend level, meaning you will be authenticated in the web session of your backend. You need to share your web session if you have multiple backend nodes.
